# Limit of a 31st order linear recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

We have the recursive sequence $y_k=k$ for $1\leq k \leq 31$ and $31y_{k+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{30}y_{k-i}$ for $k\geq 31$.
How do we find the limit?

This was an exam question and the answer given to me is $$\lim _{k\to \infty}y_k=\dfrac{1^2+2^2+3^2\dots+31^2}{1+2+3+\dots+31}=21.$$

I fail to understand how this makes any sense. Also, it would be nice if answers are elementary as this was on a mock test for JEE Main.

Comment: It doesn't. Assume that $y_k$ are zero or all negative for $k\leq 31$, then you can't end up with a positive limit.

Comment: @savick01 $y_k=k $ for $k\leq 31$!

Comment: @savick01 He's assumed they're all equal to $k$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $y_k$ are all positive, then you get infinity at the limit.

Comment: That was an error due to an editor, which I've corrected. It should have said $31 y_{k+1}$, not $y_{k+1}$. (and thank you, TMM, for fixing the mistake I made - I slightly misread, and thought it was $y_0$ to $y_{30}$ that was defined)

Comment: @Mhenni and julien: Please do take more care when approving edits. This one should not have been approved the way it was.

Comment: If generating functions are elementary enough, converting the recursion into a formula for $Y(s)=\sum\limits_{k\geqslant1}y_ks^k$ and considering the limit of $Y(s)$ when $s\to1$, one can prove that the limit of $y_k$ is the ratio of $1\cdot y_1+2\cdot y_2+\cdots+31\cdot y_{31}$ by $1+2+\cdots+31$. Otherwise I do not see a way at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
y_{k+1}=\frac{1}{31}\sum_{i=0}^{30} y_{k-i}
$$

Consider that the characteristic polynomial for this recurrence relation has a root at 1. Dividing by $(x-1)$, we can get a new characteristic polynomial. Let's assume that

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{30} (n+1)y_{k+n}=c_k
$$
Now, $c_k=c$ is a constant. Proof? Consider the difference between two successive values, here:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{31} ny_{k+n}-\sum_{n=0}^{30} (n+1)y_{k+n}=c_{k+1}-c_k\\
31y_{k+31}+\sum_{n=1}^{30}ny_{k+n}-\sum_{n=1}^{30} ny_{k+n}-\sum_{n=0}^{30}y_{k+n}=c_{k+1}-c_k\\
31y_{k+31}=c_{k+1}-c_k+\sum_{n=0}^{30}y_{k+n}
$$
Which, from our original recurrence relation, means that $c_{k+1}=c_k$, and therefore it is a constant.

So what is $c$? Let's look at the defining values - $y_k=k$ for $1\leq k\leq 31$. Take our new relation for $k=1$. So

$$
c = \sum_{n=0}^{30} (n+1)(n+1) = \sum_{n=0}^{30} (n+1)^2
$$
Now, in the limit, the values will all be equal - that is, $\lim_{n\to \infty} y_k = \lim_{n\to \infty} y_{k+1} = y$. So we have

$$
c = \sum_{n=0}^{30} (n+1)y\\
y = \frac{c}{\sum_{n=0}^{30} (n+1)} = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{30} (n+1)^2}{\sum_{n=0}^{30} (n+1)}
$$

Comment: Nice (+1). If the limit exists.

Comment: Existence of the limit can be proved without any knowledge about recurrence. Just by noticing that the $(n+k+1)$th term is between $\min_{i\leq k} y_{n+i}$ and $\max_{i\leq k} y_{n+i}$ in the distance at least $\frac{1}{k} (\max - \min)$ from the bounds.